Combining yearly data broken up into periods, into yearly data that combines the periods together
I have a data set, with a 'Year' column, a 'Period' Column, in addition to other columns with different features.  Unfortunaterly, the yearly data is broken up into the following periods, in the 'Period' column: 'JAN THRU MAR', 'APR THRU JUN', 'JUL THRU SEP', 'OCT THRU DEC'.
I want to have the 'Periods' combined, to have data for the whole year. How can I do this in python pandas?
I started a function, and I'm stuck...
    months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
    start_mo, end_mo = period.split('THRU')
    start_date = f'{start_month} {Year}'
    end_date = f'{end_month} {Year}'```


Please add an example of your data

Grouping the records by year makes it possible for you to compile your data into annual summaries. After that, you'll going to combine the data from every period for every year. In order to create a single, interrelated post for the full year, this requires setting up figures or merging text data.
It's a simple method to turn your quarterly segmented data into an easily readable annual dataset. This method will help in providing a full, well-organized view of the year's data.

Your answer could be improved if you also shared the actual code that does what you describe. Descriptions of code are okay, code can be copy-pasted and tested by anyone. You can [edit] to improve your answer.
